# Can't Open .csv File with C++

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to write a code that will open a .csv file. However, the actual file does not open. Instead it, jumps straight to the else statement at the end. I have no clue why because this should work. This is including the fstream library.

[image]

```
ifstream ycratel; //create the stream object

ycratel.open("YC Rate Levels.csv");

if (ycratel.is_open())
{
    while (ycratel.good())
    {
        //random stuff here
    }

    ycratel.close();

}

else cout << "Unable to open file.";
```

Comment: The file must reside in the same directory your program started in. Unlikely your program is started in the Resource directory.

Comment: For other files format it's work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the file format at all. Just that source code and resource csv are in different folders as clearly evident from the Solution Explorer.

```
ycratel.open("./Resource Files/YC Rate Levels.csv");
```

should do the job

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to C++ and probably should have realized that through logic alone.

Comment: @user5619709 : You're welcome. Everybody has a first time :)